# HTML/CSS Two auto-width columns

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I'm having an incredibly difficult time achieving the following effect:

```
==========================================================
= Variable Width =  <input style="width: 100%" />        =
==========================================================
```

I am using the following HTML:

```
<dl>
  <dt>
    <label>Variable Width</label>
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <input style="width: 100%" />
  </dd>
</dl>
```

*Please note that I've trimmed down the HTML for readability.*

Can anyone suggest what CSS I should use to achieve this effect? I would prefer to not have to use `display: table` because I am looking for cross-browser compatibility that reaches IE7.

Comment: What are you trying to get it to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is "incredibly difficult" to do without `<table>` or `display: table`.. until you know how!

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/aLgwt/

This works in IE7 and greater + all modern browsers.

```
dt {
    float: left
}
dd {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 4px 0 9px
}
dd input {
    width: 100%
}
```

An explanation of why it works [is here](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).

Comment: I nominate you for official *CSS God*... I had everything except for `overflow: hidden`...

Comment: Ah, but can you have more than one dt/dd and have them share the same auto-calculated width like in tables?  That's what I would like to see without JavaScript.  :)

Answer (score 0):

BTW, if you want to have the right column fixed but the left one with auto-with you can change this pattern to:

**CSS:**

```
dt {
    float: right;
}
dd {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 4px 0 9px;
}
dd input {
    width: 100%
}
```

Notice, that `label` should follow before `input` anyway.